# How to change the root path of a python project

Tags: python, import, path

I am using MacOS with Pycharm.
My directory structure:

[image]

Inside test2_main.py, I run

```py
from test1 import x
```

ModuleNotFoundError error

```py
from test1 import x
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test1'
```

How can I solve it if I want to use the same import code?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/714063/2650341

Comment: @xprilion not really, cause I don't want to change the input way/code

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Run**->**Edit Configurations** and in the menu of your Run Configuration there is a field called **Working directory**.

Comment: I tried, and no matter what directory I changed to, the error was still the same.

Comment: But when I run `os.getcwd()`, the current path is changed correctly based on my correction of the working directory.

Comment: That is very strange. I just replicated your exact folder structure and it works just fine. The only difference is I am running PyCharm on Windows. Maybe someone running on Mac can also try...

Comment: yes, I'm using Mac...hope someone can try

Comment: btw what should my working directory be? want to make sure I am right